# Does glColorMask affect glClear

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

What should the following code do assuming something was drawn before the code below?

```
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
```

Should this code just set the alpha to 1 or will it clear the color buffer?

Or in other words, does `glColorMask` affect what `glClear` does or does it only apply to normal draw operations?

I am asking specifically with regards to OpenGL ES 2.0 so any reference to a spec will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

It will clear the alpha channel only.

> The pixel ownership test, the scissor test, dithering, and the *buffer writemasks* affect the operation of [glClear](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml)